# Complex Seed generator for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, seed, seeding

Does anyone know a seed generator that can generate seeds for related entities?

Let's look at a blog for example. I would like to create seeds in the following order

- Authors
- Articles (based on Author seeds created earlier)

I can obviously write this myself. But was wondering if there is not a generic package that does this already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use faker.js for example. Check a docs [here](http://marak.github.io/faker.js/)

```
console.log(faker.fake("{{name.lastName}}, {{name.firstName} {{name.suffix}}"));
// outputs: "Marks, Dean Sr."
```

I think you can find something suitable for an article name in docs (company.companyName or commerce.productName)

Answer (score 0):

I initialy asked this question because i was planning to write a package for such a need. I wanted to make sure that something like this does not exist already.

[The package can be found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superseed/superseed)

Sample use

```js
   // create new seeder
  const seeder = new Seeder();
  // add a seed job
  seeder.addJob('users', userGenerator, userSource, {count: 2})
    .addJob('articles', articleGenerator, articlSource, {count: 3})
    // seed top categories
    .addJob('categories', categoryGenerator, categorySource, {
      staticFieldData: [
        {
          name: 'Health',
          parentId: null
        },
        {
          name: 'Fashion',
          parentId: null
        }
      ]
    })
    // seed child categories (they would use the ID of already seeded top categories as parentId)
    // notice the addSeed here. addJob can be called only once per entity.
    .addSeed('categories', {count: 3});
```